# Why Hana M_CACHES view - TOTAL_SIZE always shows -1 value?

Tags: hana

I am new to HANA and I am monitoring the Hana Cache from M_CACHES view. In this view I am constantly getting TOTAL_SIZE as -1 value and USED_SIZE as some 375 byte value.

I want to know that why TOTAL_SIZE value is coming as -1? Means does it mean something from HANA perspective?

I have checked the document also for this column as per it - "The maximum available memory budget in bytes available for the cache instance" It is available memory for cache and Used Cache has some value then why I am getting this -1 constantly?

Comment: I'd say you chose an interesting approach to learn HANA by looking at some relatively unimportant internal view first... anyway, please post the output of M_CACHES and the version you're using.

Comment: Output - CACHE_ID | CS_QueryResultCache[Realtime] | TOTAL_SIZE | -1 | USED_SIZE | 327 | and version is - SP12

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had a moment to check this and with current HANA 1.0 revisions the value for TOTAL_SIZE in M_CACHES is indeed always -1.
Looks like this column had been planned for some use but never got implemented.

Comment: Thank you very much for your information. Is USED_SIZE is also not implemented? Or it is implemented and can be used for monitoring? As for all processes it is showing the 375 bytes values. Just want to confirm on this.

Comment: USED_SIZE is implemented, but CACHES that show up in M_CACHES are not necessarily used by default. Some caches need to be configured or explicitly used. Note that for SAP HANA caches are used a lot less compared with disk-based database engines, since all data is in RAM anyway.